# Function not working with print and gsub

Tags: r

Any idea how to get this function to work? I want it to print "Seq is DNA, converting to RNA.." or "Seq is RNA" for the 20 lines in the column and then apply the gsub to the empty column but it doesn't work. What I get is a print for the first line and the gsub doesn't work.

```
     `$DNA.RNA = function(check.string){
      grep = grepl("[^ACGT]",seq.mat[1:20,2])
      DNAorRNA = ifelse(grep == "FALSE", print("Seq is DNA, converting to 
      RNA.."), print("Seq is RNA"))
      DNAorRNA = as.list(DNAorRNA)
      seq.mat[,3] = gsub("T", "U", seq.mat[,2])
      }`
```

without the seq.mat[,3] code line, this will print in the rstudio console when i run the function

```
   `$[1] "Seq is DNA, converting to RNA.."
    [[1]]
    [1] "Seq is DNA, converting to RNA.."
    [[2]]
    [1] "Seq is DNA, converting to RNA.."
    [[3]]
    [1] "Seq is DNA, converting to RNA.."
    [[4]]
    [1] "Seq is DNA, converting to RNA.."
    [[5]]
    [1] "Seq is DNA, converting to RNA.."
    [[6]]
    [1] "Seq is DNA, converting to RNA.."
    [[7]]
    [1] "Seq is DNA, converting to RNA.."
    [[8]]
    [1] "Seq is DNA, converting to RNA.."
    [[9]]
    [1] "Seq is DNA, converting to RNA.."
    [[10]]
    [1] "Seq is DNA, converting to RNA.."
    [[11]]
    [1] "Seq is DNA, converting to RNA.."
    [[12]]
    [1] "Seq is DNA, converting to RNA.."
    [[13]]
    [1] "Seq is DNA, converting to RNA.."
    [[14]]
    [1] "Seq is DNA, converting to RNA.."  
    [[15]]
    [1] "Seq is DNA, converting to RNA.."
    [[16]]
    [1] "Seq is DNA, converting to RNA.."
    [[17]]
    [1] "Seq is DNA, converting to RNA.."
    [[18]]
    [1] "Seq is DNA, converting to RNA.."
    [[19]]
    [1] "Seq is DNA, converting to RNA.."
    [[20]]
    [1] "Seq is DNA, converting to RNA.."
    `
```

the seq.mat[,3] line i wanted to use to convert the data from one column to another if the printed lines expressed that specific quote and replace all of the T's with U's.

Comment: Please show a small reproducible example.  `grep` is a function and assigning  functions as object names are not good.  In your function, you are not returning anything.  So, it is not clear when you say `gsub doesn't work`

Comment: The function is a mess. It has an argument that is *never*  used by the function, it refers to an object `seq.mat` that is not an argument (possible but always a bad idea), it returns nothing, the instruction before last does nothing. Whatever `not working` means, it's an understatement.

Comment: Thanks, I noticed that. Does my edit help clarify anything?

Comment: What do you want your function to return? A modified `seq.mat` or `DNAorRNA`?

Comment: a modified seq.mat

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, you want:

1. to check whether or not `'ACGT'` is part of the elements in `seq.mat[, 2]`.
2. If that's the case, then you are dealing with DNA, which you want to convert RNA, right?
3. Then you want to give column 3 of `seq.math` the valid RNA values.
4. You convert from DNA to RNA by replacing every letter `'T'` in DNA elements with a `'U'`, right?

This is based on your question, I know nothing about DNA, RNA or anything like it.

```
# Part 1:
dna_check <- grepl("ACGT", seq.math[, 2])

# Part 2-3:
seq.math[!dna_check, 3] <- seq.math[!dna_check, 2]
seq.math[dna_check, 3]  <- gsub("T", "U", seq.mat[dna_check, 2])
```

My guess is that this will go extremely quick and printing the messages will only slow things down. In case you really want to print some message in between, you should use a `for`-loop or so and print a message at the end of every iteration.

*Side notes based on your question*: There are a couple of things in your question that are confusing, superfluous or even wrong. I figured I'll point them out so you can learn from them. Firstly, you define a function that takes `check.string` as an argument, but you never use it inside the function. Secondly, you are saving a `print` call in a list. There is no good reason (as far as I know) to do that. If you want to save a message in a list, just do quotes like `my_list <- ifelse(check, "message1", "message2")`. Thirdly, it is a bad idea to define objects with the same name as an R function, as Akrun pointed out in his comment. Also, why do your convert `DNAorRNA` to a list? And finally, I think it is a good idea to use a return statement in your self-defined functions. Even though it is not necessary per se, it helps you organise what it is that your function actually outputs when it runs.